# 3D plot in Matlab with loops

Tags: matlab, loops, plot

I'm trying to plot a network using some input data. The Network consists of points and lines, which are called from a file. Here is what the code look like:

```
figure
hold on
loop#1 start
     % read the coordination of lines
     pos(1,1)= from input
     pos(1,2)= from input
     pos(1,3)= from input
     pos(2,1)= from input
     pos(2,2)= from input
     pos(2,3)= from input

     plot3(pos(:,1), m_pos(:,2), m_pos(:,3), '-', 'LineWidth', 0.5);
loop#1 end

loop#2 start
     %read coordination of points
     coord= from input
     plot3(coord(1), coord(2),coord(3),'o');
loop#2 end
```

What I get at the end, is a 2D plot (NOT 3D) in which both points and lines are plotted. But it is in 2D.
I have tried different things, e.g. bringing plot3 functions out of the mail loops.

Any idea??

UPDATE: It seems to be a bug. I ran the same code on my work PC (Win10, Matlab 2016) and it works. It seems something is wrong with compatibility of MATLAB 2015 and my Vista.

Comment: Are you sure you're not just viewing it top down so it looks 2d? Try `view(3)`

Comment: yes, I'm sure. It shows only if I plot3 with one object (line or point), but with loop (either just one loop or both loops) it doesn't.

Comment: To get help with this you'll need to post a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the issue. We cannot run the code you posted to see what might be going on.

Comment: UPDATE: It seems to be a bug. I ran the same code on my work PC (Win10, Matlab 2016) and it works. It seems something is wrong with compatibility of MATLAB 2015 and my Vista.